# How to use Collectors toMap() to return single value?

Tags: java

I am trying to get Collectors toMap() working to return single value from set of headers.
For example: input string

[clients:MYSQL,EDW,Oracle,WSO2,SMTP, UniqueName:Domain_v1]

code:

```
private static Map<String, Object> headersTomap(String headers) {
      String sHeaders = headers.replace("[", ""); sHeaders = sHeaders.replace("]",
      ""); logger.debug("sHeaders: " + sHeaders); return
      Arrays.stream(sHeaders.split(", ")).map(s -> s.split(":"))
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1]));

      }
```

Above code returns:

```
clients: MYSQL,EDW,Oracle,WSO2,SMTP
UniqueName: Domain_v1
```

Expected output is: Domain_v1

Please advise. The above code should return Domain_v1 as output for above input. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: why can't you do `map.get("UniqueName") `? `Collectors.toMap()` returns a map .Its not for returning single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already converted string to `Map`, you can get the value for `UniqueName` key by using [getOrDefault](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-)

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or defaultValue if this map contains no mapping for the key.

```
Map<String,String> map = Arrays.stream(sHeaders.split(", ")).map(s -> s.split(":"))
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1]));

 map.getOrDefault("UniqueName","Not Present");
```

Or in one sequence

```
Arrays.stream(sHeaders.split(", ")).map(s -> s.split(":"))
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1]))
  .getOrDefault("UniqueName","Not Present");
```

If you just need value associated to `UniqueName` without `Map` then you can simply go for this approach

```
String res = Arrays.stream(sHeaders.split(", "))
                       .filter(s->s.contains("UniqueName:"))
                       .findFirst()
                       .map(name->name.split(":")[1])
                       .orElse("Not Present");
```

Comment: This returns Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Map<String,Object> error

Comment: If you want to return `String`  just change return type to `String`, or you want to return that `MAP` with only `UniqueName: Domain_v1` @pitsa ? What do you want to return ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I need to return the value of UniqueName ie Domain_v1.

Comment: Then just change the return type of that method to  `String` @pitsa

Comment: Appreciate your help. Thank you so much @Deadpool